# ReferenceError: str is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Im very new to javascript Im working through the [w3school tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_string_replace), trying to replace all occurrences within a certain string.

I have the following string `08/18/16` I would like to replace all occurences of `/` to `,`

As per W3schools example I try to achieve the above as follow:

`date1 = str.replace("/",",");`

However the above results in an error

> ReferenceError: str is not defined date1 = str.replace("/",",")

I would really appreciate it if someone could give the following code a scan.

```
var firstDate = document.getElementById("firstDate").value;
var secondDate = document.getElementById("secondDate").value;
var date1 = firstDate.substring(0,11);
var date2 = secondDate.substring(0,11);
date1 = str.replace("/",",");
date2 = str.replace("/",",");
```

Comment: `str` is not defined not var str is initialized

Comment: To replace all occurrences, you need a regex with a global modifier.

Comment: `str` is the variable containing the string you wish to do a replace on. If you copied it directly from the example it wont work as you have no variable called `str`.

Comment: I think you need `date1 = date1.replace(/\//g, ",");`

Comment: You have to declare me `var str;` before you can use me. Greetings `str`.

Comment: First tell us what firstDate  contains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ReferenceError: str is not defined

The issue tells you that the `str` variable should be defined first to be able to perform a `replace` on it.

To replace *all* `/` with `,` you need a `/\//g` (where `/.../` are the regex delimiters, `\/` matches a literal `/` and `g` enables *global*, multiple replacements) regex as a `replace` with a string as the first argument will only replace once:

```js
var str = "08/18/16";
var res = str.replace(/\//g, ",");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed input. I assume I can replace `08/18/16` with a variable so it will be `date.replace(/\//g, ",");`

Comment: Yes, you can replace the string literal with a variable. Just do not forget to declare and initialize it. I edited the snippet to show that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any variable called `str` , so it will not work .
Try this code:

```
  var firstDate = document.getElementById("firstDate").value;
    var secondDate = document.getElementById("secondDate").value;
    var date1 = firstDate.substring(0,11);
    var date2 = secondDate.substring(0,11);
    date1 = date1 .replace("/",",");
    date2 = date2 .replace("/",",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare `str` variable, so declare as `var str`.

```
var firstDate = document.getElementById("firstDate").value;
var secondDate = document.getElementById("secondDate").value;
var str;
var date1 = firstDate.substring(0,11);
str = date1;
date1 = str.replace("/",",");
var date2 = secondDate.substring(0,11);
str = date2;    
date2 = str.replace("/",",");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateStr = "08/18/16";
var individualStr = dateStr.split('/');
var newStr = individualStr[0]+','+individualStr[1]+','+individualStr[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstDate = document.getElementById("firstDate").value;
var secondDate = document.getElementById("secondDate").value;
var date1 = firstDate.substring(0,11);
var date2 = secondDate.substring(0,11);
date1 = str.replace("/",",");
date2 = str.replace("/",",");
```

this code wont work here because the `replace` in java-script can be used for strings but the value you are getting from id as date format thats why it wont work.

And `replace` will only replace the first occurred once. try this code in console using regular expressions and it will replace all.

```
var firstDate = "31/11/2016";
var secondDate = "31/11/2016";
var date1 = firstDate.substring(0,11);
var date2 = secondDate.substring(0,11);
date1 = date1 .replace(/\//g,",");
date2 = date2 .replace(/\//g,","); 
alert(date1);
alert(date2);
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure the type:  String (the S is a capital letter).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).